# Calculation algorithm for Dates

Tags: c#, date, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have previously posted this question. However I was not specific enough, so I am trying to explain it better in this post.

I am currently writing a small program to create invoices. The invoices should be calculated on account of storage time of items e.g. `costPerDay * numberOfDaysInStorage`.

The invoice is created on a monthly basis, e.g. `InvoiceDate = 31/05/2013.`

The items start date and end date (in storage) is extracted from a database.

So, I have:

**Variables:**

```
 DateTime StartInStorageDate; 
 DateTime EndOfStorageDate;
 DateTime InvoiceDate; //(always last date of month)
```

**Rules**

- The first five days in storage should always be free.
- Calculation of days, should only be made for a given invoice date.
- If the date prior to the InvoiceDate exist, the days should be taken
  into account, in order to calculate the "free days". If month date prior has 5 or more   days, to the end of its month, we have to assume that these have been calculated, and therefore not take them into account in the invoice month.

**Examples**

- Example 1:

  `DateTime StartInStorageDate = 07/04/2013;`

  `DateTime EndOfStorageDate = 08/06/2013;`

  `DateTime InvoiceDate = 31/05/2013;`

  Calculation of days = 31 days (Because Invoice date has a date prior, which has more           than five days, the "free days" are already
  subtracted    in that month)
- Example 2:

  `DateTime StartInStorageDate = 28/04/2013`

  `DateTime EndOfStorageDate = 08/06/2013`

  `DateTime InvoiceDate = 31/05/2013`

  Calculation of days = (11 days total - 5 "free days") = 6 days
  (Because Invoice date has a date prior, which does not have 5 days to
  end of its month, we have to add these days to the invoice month, and
  subtract 5 "free days" from the total)
- Example 3:

  `DateTime StartInStorageDate = 28/04/2013`

  `DateTime EndOfStorageDate = 08/05/2013`

  `DateTime InvoiceDate = 31/04/2013`

  Calculation of days = 0 (Because the invoiceDate does not have more than 5 days, and does not have a month prior)

I hope someone can provide me with some pointers, or some code to help calculate the days. The part I find tricky, is to "look into" a previous month (if one exists) from the invoice date, to check for days.

Thank you.

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to do, but it looks like you should take a look at [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timespan.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate two dates: the start and end of the invoice period:

```
DateTime invoiceStart = StartInStorageDate.AddDays(5);
DateTime invoiceEnd = InvoiceDate < EndOfStorageDate ? InvoiceDate : EndOfStorageDate; 

double billedDays = Math.Max(0, (invoiceEnd - invoiceStart).TotalDays);
```

Answer (score 2):

It requires only a few simple actions:

```
DateTime endDate = Min(invoiceDate, endOfStorageDate );    // Min() is pseudo code
int daysInStorage = (endDate - StartInStorageDate).Days;
daysInStorage -= 5;
if (daysInStorage < 0) daysInStorage = 0;
```

Comment: For `Min` I'd do something like this: `DateTime endDate = new DateTime(Math.Min(invoiceDate.Ticks, endOfStorageDate.Ticks));`

Comment: Or simply `DateTime endDate = invoiceDate < endOfStorageDate ? invoiceDate : endOfStorageDate;`